# Product of two separable spaces separable

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that the product of two nonempty separable spaces is separable.

Attempt:Let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonempty separable spaces. Let $A$ be a countable and dense subset of $X$. Let $B$ be a countable and dense subset of $Y$. Since the cartesian product of two countable sets is countable, $A \times B$ is a countable subset of $X \times Y$. Also $\overline {A \times B}=\bar A \times \bar B=X \times Y$ so $A \times B$ is dense.

Comment: I have looked at a proof of this result using projection functions so I am unsure if the strategy I used is correct. Is it really this simple, or is there an issue or flaw with this approach?

Comment: Did you mean  $\overline {A \times B}=\bar A \times \bar {\color{red}B}=X \times \color{red}Y$ where you typed   $\overline {A \times B}=\bar A \times \bar Y=X \times B$  ?

Comment: Yes I did thanks

Comment: You need to justify your claim that $\overline{A\times B} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, but apart from that your approach is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem whatsoever with this approach.You  *do* have to prove (or know) that $$\overline{A \times B} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$$

for all $A \subseteq X, B \subseteq Y$, but after that it's really that simple (for finite products).

There are many ways to approach this problem: another is to use the fact that $D$ is dense iff every basic non-empty open subset of the whole space intersects $D$, applied to basic sets of the form $U \times V$, e.g.